# Javascript to show/hide name field on comment form?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I hide `nickname` field by default, then show it when the user clicks on the textarea?

```
<div class="input-box">
<textarea name="detail" placeholder="Input here" id="review_field" cols="5" rows="3" class="required-entry"></textarea>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-8" >
<input type="text" name="nickname" placeholder="input name!" id="nickname_field" class="input-text required-entry"  />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the nickname field, set `display: none` on the nickname, assign a click handler to the textarea which removes the display setting returning it to it's natural state.

```js
var nickname = document.getElementById('nickname_field');
nickname.style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById("review_field").onclick = function() {
    nickname.style.display = '';
};
```

```html
<div class="input-box">
<textarea name="detail" placeholder="Input here" id="review_field" cols="5" rows="3" class="required-entry"></textarea>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-8" >
<input type="text" name="nickname" placeholder="input name!" id="nickname_field" class="input-text required-entry"  />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this following code :

```
  $(function(){
    // hide nickname field on initial dom ready state
    $('#nickname_field').hide();  
    // add click event onto review_field    
    $('#review_field').click(function(){
      //show nickname field when textarea was clicked
      $('#nickname_field').show();
    });
 });
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/metallurgical/hhnnrypm/)**

Answer (score 0):

Use css to hide the element initially. If you use JS to hide it there may be a moment while the page is loading that the element may be visible.

```js
$('#review_field').on('click', function() {
  $('#nickname_field').show();
});
```

```css
#nickname_field {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-box">
<textarea name="detail" placeholder="Input here" id="review_field" cols="5" rows="3" class="required-entry"></textarea>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-8" >
<input type="text" name="nickname" placeholder="input name!" id="nickname_field" class="input-text required-entry"  />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution:

```js
var nickName = $('#nickname_field');
var reviewField = $('#review_field');

nickName.hide();

reviewField.on('keypress keydown keyup', function(){
  
 nickName.show();
  
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-box">
<textarea name="detail" placeholder="Input here" id="review_field" cols="5" rows="3" class="required-entry"></textarea>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-8" >
<input type="text" name="nickname" placeholder="input name!" id="nickname_field" class="input-text required-entry"  />
</div>
```